# JS adds blank image name from a php script parsing through the dir

Tags: javascript, php

There is a page with infinite scroll gallery, it works fine, but in the end of the script it appends 1 img which is blank and makes 1 image broken and again. Can't understand whats the issue :(

Is there any solution how remove it from feed with JS or there is a mystake with php parser?

JS CODE

```js
  var contentHeight = 800;
  var pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrollPosition;
  var n = 9;
  var xmlhttp;
  
  function putImages(){
       
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText){
               var resp = xmlhttp.responseText.replace("\r\n", ""); 
               resp=resp.replace("\r", ""); 
               resp=resp.replace("\n", ""); 
               var files = resp.split(";");
                var j = 0;
                for(i=0; i<=files.length; i++){
                    if(files[i] != ""){
                       document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += ' <div class="masonry-brick" ><div class="item masonry-item"><img src="https://site.eu/img/'+files[i]+'" alt="Masonry Brick" class="masonry-content"/></div></div>';
                       j++;
                     
                       if(j == 3 || j == 6)
                            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '';
                        else if(j == 9){
                            //document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<p>'+(n-1)+" Images Displayed | <a href='#header'>top</a></p><hr />";
                            j = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
           
           
  function scroll(){
       
      if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
          scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      else
          scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;        
       
      if((contentHeight - pageHeight - scrollPosition) < 500){
                   
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          else
              if(window.ActiveXObject)
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              else
                  alert ("Bummer! Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");         
             
          var url="https://site.eu/gallery/getImages.php?n="+n;
           
          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
           
          n += 9;
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=putImages;       
          contentHeight += 800;       
      }
  
  }
```

PHP Code

```
$dir = "../../../img";
 $allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
 $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 

     if(is_dir($dir)){
         if($dd = opendir($dir)){
             while (($f = readdir($dd)) !== false)
               if(!in_array($f,[".","..",".htaccess"," "]))
                   $files[] = $f;
                   $allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');
                  // $ext = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                   closedir($dd);
     } 
  

     $n = $_GET["n"];
     $response = "";
         for($i = $n; $i<$n+10; $i++){
             $response = $response.$files[$i%count($files)].';';
         }
         echo $response;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the putImages Javascript function, line shown below:

```
for(i=0; i<=files.length; i++){
```

This for loop is running one too many times because you have "i is less than **or equal** to files.length". Because i starts at zero you want just "less than" here. i.e.:

```
for(i=0; i<files.length; i++){
```

Because it was going an extra loop, files[i] was returning "undefined". Undefined is not empty string so it passed the if statement and tried to output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that's still the same every 10 item is empty https://site.eu/img/*needs to be an image name* and 11 is undefined. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I set up your code in my test environment and that was definitely the cause. The empty item is fine and expected because you send back a string that has a trailing semi colon so when you split the string the last item is empty. You handle that with your if statement anyway. Add a console.log statement after var files = resp.split(";"); to check what it has. I am sure you will see 10 images and the last one empty string.

Comment: Understood about the first 1, but the problem is that its images 1 is undefined and 2nd is just empty.  https://prnt.sc/tn9x9b

Comment: I can see on your site (from that screenshot) that the change I suggested has not been made, are you developing on a different site? If I can see the actual site then it might help, what is the url path if you don't want to share domain, I already got that from the screenshot.

Comment: thats ok, I believe there is some issues with the uploading the js file, since, there is no chages in it. However, as you can see there is to broken images, first one because of the <= and the second one no idea why, to be honest.

Comment: In your img folder you have an image with a really long strange filename, perhaps that could be causing the problem of empty img src. Maybe try rename that one file? The undefined problem is because of what I already mentioned to change.

Comment: OK, for me I still got the old code because if some caching further down the line, loading v5.3.2. If I change the version number I get the updated code so maybe you want to check that you are not using cached version too.

Comment: Well, got the console.log and the last element is "enter" ["IMG_3324.jpeg", "IMG_20200502_132434_801.jpg", "20200429_115246.jpg", "FullSizeRender (5).jpg", "IMG_20200430_155710.jpg", "20200429_123302.jpg", "FullSizeRender.jpg", "IMG_20200502_132518_217.jpg", "FullSizeRender (2).jpg", "IMG_20200430_102554_396.jpg", "
↵"] What is this? Thats JS that i'm using atm https://codepen.io/ultrapanam/pen/RwrdWWd

Comment: That strange symbol is likely to be coming from PHP. I don't think it is a carriage return or linefeed. Is there anything following the PHP after what you have shared in the question? You don't have ?> at the end of the file do you?

Comment: I have closing tag. I've just replaced the sign and it works now. Thank you very much for your time and the answer :)

Comment: OK, my suggestion is remove the closing tag because anything after the closing tag will also be returned to the browser. I bet there is a blank line or hidden character after the closing tag. I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: ofc, you've helped me a lot :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

Instead of this
`resp=resp.replace("\r", "");  resp=resp.replace("\n", "");`

it needs to be like this

`resp=resp.replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r|↵)/gm", "");  resp=resp.replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r|↵)/gm", "");`